# Can you capture and inspect arguments supplied to a method under test with ScalaMock?

Tags: scala, mocking, scalatest

The Java Mocking framework Mockito has a utility class called `ArgumentCaptor` that accumulates a list of values as a method under verification is invoked multiple times.

Does ScalaMock have a similar mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an under the hood mechanism that does this in the [preview release of ScalaMock3](http://www.paulbutcher.com/2012/06/scalamock-3-0-preview-release/), but it's not currently exposed to client code.

What's your use case for this?

You might be able to achieve what you need by using `where` or `onCall` documented [here](http://scalamock.org/user-guide/advanced_topics/) (under the "Predicate matching" and "Return Value" headings respectively).

Comment: Good question. The use case is exactly what you'd use `ArgumentCaptors` for: ensuring that the sequence of invocations are passed exactly the values that you'd expect. I think ultimately used `onCall` to accumulate a list of results before running verification over them.

Comment: The link at "here" is broken now. Maybe http://scalamock.org/user-guide/advanced_topics/ is a suitable replacement.

Comment: @Paul Has this been added to ScalaMock 4.x? I feel argument matching isn't exactly argument capture.

Comment: I've handed maintenance of ScalaMock over to Philipp Meyerhoefer https://github.com/barkhorn

Answer (score 2):

In [Specs2](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/) you can use the following:

```
myMock.myFunction(argument) answers(
    passedArgument => "something with"+passedArgument
)
```

This maps to Mockito's ArgumentCaptor under the hood.

Comment: This way the `passedArgument`'s type is `Any`. Is there any way to maintain its type information inside the closure? This way I have to cast it in order to use its members.

Comment: I think you'd have to declare the type. `passedArgument:Mine => …` is as good as it gets for me without doing real work of course.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Mockito documentation](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.0/org.specs2.guide.UseMockito.html#with-matchers), you can use specs2 matchers directly, e.g.

```
val myArgumentMatcher: PartialFunction[ArgumentType, MatchResult[_]] = {
  case argument => argument mustEqual expectedValue
}
there was one(myMock).myFunction(beLike(myArgumentMatcher))
```

The cool thing about this solution is that the partial function allows for really great flexibility. You can pattern match on your argument, etc. Of course, if you really just need to compare the argument value, then there's no need for the partial function, you can just do

```
there was one(myMock).myFunction(==_(expectedValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to implement your own argument captor by extending the existing matchers. Something of the kind should do the trick (For scalamock 3) :

```
trait TestMatchers extends Matchers {

    case class ArgumentCaptor[T]() {
        var valueCaptured: Option[T] = None
    }

    class MatchAnyWithCaptor[T](captor: ArgumentCaptor[T]) extends MatchAny {
        override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = {
           captor.valueCaptured = Some(that.asInstanceOf[T])
           super.equals(that)
        }
    }

    def capture[T](captor: ArgumentCaptor[T]) = new MatchAnyWithCaptor[T](captor)
}
```

You can use this new matcher by adding that trait to your test class

```
val captor = new ArgumentCaptor[MyClass]

(obj1.method(_: MyClass)).expects(capture(captor)).returns(something)

println(captor.capturedValue)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [ArgumentCapture](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/specs2/mock/mockito/CapturedArgument.scala):

```
val subject = new ClassUnderTest(mockCollaborator)
// Create the argumentCapture
val argumentCapture = new ArgumentCapture[ArgumentClazz]

// Call the method under test
subject.methodUnderTest(methodParam)

// Verifications
there was one (mockCollaborator).someMethod(argumentCapture)
val argument = argumentCapture.value
argument.getSomething mustEqual methodParam
```